# NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, kapt

I added a new Retrofit interface to my project containing a couple of Endpoints annotated with the `@GET` and `@HEADERS` annotations, after Injecting said interface to a repository class using the `@Inject` annotation in the constructor of said class, Android Studio throws this error:

```
NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
```

After taking a look at the generated Java code, it replaces the `@GET` and `@HEADERS` annotations with this:

```
@error.NonExistentClass()
```

I've already tried the following:

- Using `annotatioProcessor` instead of `kapt`
- Setting `jetifier.enabled` to `false` in `gradle.properties`
- Setting `generateStubs` to `true` in my `build.gradle` file
- Setting `correctErrorTypes` to `true` in my `build.gradle` file

Im using:

- Android Studio 3.3
- Kotlin 1.3.11
- Dagger 2.21
- Retrofit 2.3.0
- Kotlin
- Kapt

could it be some dagger scope issue? or Retrofit / dagger not fully compatible with the new versions of the Kapt plugin?

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: I found the solution, my proyect is multi-module and the `remote` module was containing the `retrofit` depenency, for some reason, the IDE allows accessing the `remote` module dependencies from the `app` module, adding the `retrofit` dependencies on the module solved the issue

Comment: Thanks @AlfredoBejarano I figured out my issue, took me longer than I thought it would but the error for me was actually very explicit. I will add an answer that might help others.

Answer (score 4):

Luckily this question led me to figure out my issue. While moving around classes from an app module into a library, I was referencing an annotation class which only existed in a debug folder. So debug builds were fine, but calls to `gradlew install` failed when generating release files.

The error for me was very explicit although it took me a long time to realize - the generated file had literally replaced the missing annotation with `@error.NonExistentClass()`

Moving the file into the main src set meant both debug and release builds could see the class. What took me a while to figure out was that I assumed this was a Dagger issue being masked by kapt, but really it was just a regular old Dagger issue. My advice is to look at your Dagger setup carefully.

Comment: I think the trick here is that if you were depending on a module that was depending on another module/library (for example Retrofit) but you set Retrofit to be an `implementation` dependency instead of `api` dependency, then your module would not transitively see it, and `kapt` would fail.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had recently *removed* dagger from a project and forgot to remove the @Singleton and @Inject annotations from relevant classes.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was caused by migration to view binding from kotlin-android-extensions and Android Studio couldn't find @Parcelize annotation. To add annotations back add this to build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, its painfully removing all the @Singleton and @OpenForTesting on my Module classes. And removing two DAO classes and Repository whose backing model classes is no longer annotated with @Entity.

Answer (score 0):

For me was in here:

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using this ""com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3" library, but later I removed this dependency from gradle, but didn't remove the code that I was using of this library, so removed code and annotations related to this library solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem: I was trying to use picocli's @Command annotation and was getting the same error. It turned out to be an issue with my imports. I was importing this and other annotations via a wildcard import: `import picocli.CommandLine.*`. When i replaced it with separate imports for each annotation (among which was `import picocli.CommandLine.Command`), kapt began working correctly.

I assume kapt simply doesn't understand wildcard imports.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another case:

Had this issue on some `Worker` class after removing some dependencies from the module it lived in.

The worker has the `@HiltWorker` annotation, which as far as the IDE can tell is resolved just fine: at compile time, it is replaced with the `@NonExistentClass` one and break.

The issue is solved by adding an explicit dependency to

```
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:$version")
```

Assumptions on why the issue happens:

- such dependency was imported transitively before doing some changes.
- the following dependency (which was in place all the time) somehow fools the IDE into thinking it knows `@HiltWorker` annotation

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$version")
```