# NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation - app:kaptDebugAndroidTestKotlin

Tags: kotlin, build, androidx, kapt, junit-jupiter

I want to test a class using JUnit5 but at the time gradle runs the app:kaptDebugAndroidTestKotlin task I get the issue.

I have already tried the solutions in the following links but nothing helps so far:

[NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564247/nonexistentclass-cannot-be-converted-to-annotation)

[error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation @error.NonExistentClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919848/error-incompatible-types-nonexistentclass-cannot-be-converted-to-annotation-e)

my project build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.8'
    ext.junit_version='5.5.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.11.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my module build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hays.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
        androidExtensions {
            experimental = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
}
realm {
    kotlinExtensionsEnabled = true
}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
    testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:$junit_version"
    testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx', name: 'kotlinx-coroutines-android', version: '1.3.0-M1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
}
```

and my gradle.properties file:

```
kotlin.code.style=official
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

I tried to run the test but what I get while compiling is the following:

C:\project_path\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debugAndroidTest\com\package\test\module\search\SearchPresenterTest.java:20: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
    @error.NonExistentClass()

The file under build folder has some of the following:

```
@error.NonExistentClass()
public final void setUpMocks() {
}

@error.NonExistentClass()
public final void onSearch() {
}
```

While the original kotlin test file is like the following lines:

```
@BeforeEach
fun setUpMocks() {
    clearAllMocks()

}


@Test
fun onSearch() {
    verify { view.onSearch() }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems that I mixed some JUnit4 dependencies with those of JUnit5 so by removing the following lines (like the AndroidJUnitRunner class) in the dependencies I got it working:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
kapt("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt.gradle.plugin:1.3.31:pom")
```

And I added back again those of the jupiter packages:

```
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
testImplementation "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:$junit_version"
```

Also the org.junit classes in all the tests have to be replaced by their equivalent of the org.junit.jupiter package.
That made it compile the test without issues.